# How to add an accent mark to an existing dictionary word?

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-1020, dictionary

I use a word a lot that is in the phones dictionary without an accent. I would like it to always have the accent, or at least show up in the word suggestion list so I can just click on it instead of holding down e and having to manually put in the accent each time.

After I manually type the word with the accent and click on it, I don't have the +word option I would normally have with new words to add it to the dictionary. I guess because its already in the dictionary without the accent?

Is there a way I can add it with the accent, or change the regular word to use the accent mark?

Comment: I successfully added an entry slightly different on the dictionary. Couldn't reproduce the problem you are having.

Comment: @VitorCanova Hmm. Specifically, I'm trying to add Renée, but no + sign shows up and this word never comes up as a suggestion, only Renee.

Comment: Same here. I can add "Pooorrer" to dic but not "Renée".